# Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am tring to create a stored procedure that will add a horse to my currently table but i am getting this error. Does anyone know why this error is occuring?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADDHORSE (
 HorseID IN INTEGER,
 Stable IN VARCHAR2,
 Horse_Name IN VARCHAR2,
 DateofBirth IN DATE,
 Sex Char:=1);
 Height FLOAT,
 Dam VARCHAR2:=30),
 Sire VARCHAR2:=30)
)

 AS 
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO horse(
      [HorseID],
      [Stable],
      [Horse_Name],
      [DateofBirth],
      [Sex],
      [Height],
      [Dam],
      [Sire]
  ) VALUES (
      HorseID,
      Stable,
      Horse_Name,
      DateofBirth,
      Sex,
      Height,
      Dam,
      Sire
 )
END ADDHORSE;
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer Version 3.2.20.09

Answer (score 1):

You have a semi-colon and an extra bracket in your parameter list, does this work for you...

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE ADDHORSE (
     HorseID INTEGER,
     Stable VARCHAR2,
     Horse_Name VARCHAR2,
     DateofBirth DATE,
     Sex CHAR(1),
     Height FLOAT,
     Dam VARCHAR2(30),
     Sire VARCHAR2(30)
)

 AS 
 BEGIN
      INSERT INTO horse(
          [HorseID],
          [Stable],
          [Horse_Name],
          [DateofBirth],
          [Sex],
          [Height],
          [Dam],
          [Sire]
      ) VALUES (
          HorseID,
          Stable,
          Horse_Name,
          DateofBirth,
          Sex,
          Height,
          Dam,
          Sire
     )
END ADDHORSE;
```

Comment: I Saw that this might confuse people so i edited my main code, i also edited it in my SQL and it still did not fix the problem unfortunately :\

Comment: Apologies - so used to typing SQL Server stuff!  Taken out parameter modifiers!

Comment: There was also a rogue `NULL` hanging around at the end of the insert statement.

Comment: After Pasting your Code into my SQL i still get this error "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:

   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
   current delete exists prior
"

Comment: Sorry - must have forgotten my brain today.  Try that instead.

Comment: Well that's extremely strange, i'm getting the same error even though there is no @ Symbol... hmm

Comment: Are you calling this SP from another?  If so, is there a rogue @ sign in the calling routine?

Comment: Managed to fix this by adding CREATE OR REPLACE :) The replace seemed to fix the error

Comment: Ok I seem to be getting another strange error now... I've edited my code up top for you. The error is 'Encountered the symbol HEIGHT' ? I hate SQL.. one error fixed seems to give you 10 more

Answer (score 1):

I noted you had some missing quotes (`'`) with your `varchar` and `char` and a missing ';' at the end of the `insert`.

This works for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADDHORSE (
 HorseID IN INTEGER,
 Stable IN VARCHAR2,
 Horse_Name IN VARCHAR2,
 DateofBirth IN DATE,
 Sex Char := '1',
 Height FLOAT,
 Dam VARCHAR2 := '30',
 Sire VARCHAR2 := '30'
)
 AS 
 BEGIN
     INSERT INTO horse(
      HorseID,
      Stable,
      Horse_Name,
      DateofBirth,
      Sex,
      Height,
      Dam,
      Sire
  ) VALUES (
      HorseID,
      Stable,
      Horse_Name,
      DateofBirth,
      Sex,
      Height,
      Dam,
      Sire
 );
END ADDHORSE;
```

Comment: @user3360874: You are welcome. Since you are new here, please don't forget to mark your question as answered.